# How do I properly set width to a percentile and keep a min-width in pixels?

Tags: html, width, background-image, css

So I have a header/navigation bar div, this div has a repeat-x background image.
Than I've got a horizontal navigation which is centered over this background, but needs a min-width and normal width.

I'd like for it to show up as 80% width, and min-width 1000px, and centered.

#### CSS

```
.center-wrap {
width: 80%;
min-width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#bar {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div id="bar">
    <div class"center-wrap">
        UL LI HERE
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Error

Now the problem with this is if I resize the page to below 1000px the repeat-x background image cuts off (when scrolling -> to reveal the rest of the website).

How would I go about keeping my repeat-x background image on `#bar` and keeping the center-wrap centered and include a min-width and percentile width?

Comment: Could you stick up a jsfiddle demonstrating the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your Css, Magic! :D

```
body{min-width: 1000px;}
```

The problem is that the body is taking the window object width as max width, and the descendant are taking that width as heritage. What happens is:

You resize the window(browser) to 300px width, then body's width = 300px, then .center-wrap = 80% of 300px, so setting min-width of body to a fixed number fixes it

Comment: You sir are a magician, thank you! Can't believe It was so simple, I was trying all types of positions and displays. Thanks for the explanation, I'll keep it mind for my other projects :]